# Command \* already defined ... see p.192 of the manual

Tags: macros, errors, theorems, starred-version

My code had:

```
\newtheorem*{theI}{Thesis I}
```

And it gives me the error:

```
Command \* already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

1.16 \newtheorem*{theI}{
                        Thesis I}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The standard definition of `\newtheorem` doesn't provide a star version.

Comment: `\newtheorem*` is provided by the `amsthm` package.

Comment: @Marco Daniel,egreg

Thank you guys for very fast help.

I solved this by permitting `asmthm` package (it was disabled because gave me some `\openbox redefined` error) so I put `\savesymbol{openbox}`

before `amsthm` package, and everything compiled correctly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command `\newtheorem` is defined in the LaTeX-kernel with the following input:

```
\newtheorem{name}{Printed output}[numberby]
```

or

```
\newtheorem{name}[counter]{Printed output}
```

You can see that the standard definition doesn't have a star version.

But you want an unnumbered theorem. Packages like `amsthm` or `ntheorem` provide the star version to get an unnumbered theorem. Examples are shown below.

`amsthm`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{leo}{Leo}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{leo}
Theorem without number
\end{leo}
\end{document}
```

`ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem*{leo}{Leo}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\begin{leo}
Theorem without number
\end{leo}
\end{document}
```

[image]